# Time complexity of recursive algorithm (pseudo code)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

If we have some code like this (pseudo) what is the time complexity of this recursive call? Assume that anything not stated below is considered constant time.

```
a,b,c > 0

//some code above, then we get here 

for i = 0 to a
    recursive(i,b)

//code continues

FUNCTION recursive(i,b)
if b = 0
    return 0

for j = i+c to a
    recursive(j,b-1)
ENDFUNC
```

**EDIT**
I mainly am having trouble determining whether it is exponential or not. The depth is clearly b and does a calls in recursive function which gives O(b*a), but then the main loop also calls it a times which makes me think it should be in total: O(a^2 * b), but I don't quite understand how exponential complexity is generated so am wonder if it could be that instead?

Comment: Where are you having problems analyzing the complexity by yourself? You need to count how often each function is called. This yields a number which is dependent on the used variables, like `a + 2b + c^a` or something like this. After that deriving a complexity class is very easy.

Comment: @ikegami should of written b - 1.

Comment: assume b in recursive-function is local, so doing b - 1 doesn't effect the b in the main for-loop

Comment: @tiggybits, The first thing to notice is that `b` restricts the recursion depth.

Comment: I mainly am having trouble determining whether it is exponential or not. The depth is clearly b and does a calls in recursive function which gives O(b*a), but then the main loop also calls it a times which makes me think it should be in total: O(a^2 * b), but I don't quite understand how exponential complexity is generated so am wonder if it could be that instead?

Comment: @tiggybits Please include your thoughts in the question itself by **editing**, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look at two simple nested loops first:

```
for i (1..N) {
   for j (1..N) {
      f();
   }
}

for i (1..N) {
   for j (i..N) {
      g();
   }
}
```

`f()` is called `N*N = N2 = O(N2)` times.

`g()` is called `N+(N-1)+...+5+4+3+2+1 = N(N+1)/2 = N2/2 + N/2 = O(N2)` times.

As you can see, it doesn't matter where the inner loop starts; the complexity is going to be the same.

---

Secondly, let's see what happens if you add a level of nesting.

```
for i (1..N) {
   for j (1..N) {
      for k (1..N) {
          h();
      }
   }
}
```

We already know the two outer loops are `O(N2)`, and we are doing that `N` times, so we get `O(N3)`. We can see that the exponent is the amount of nesting.

---

If we start unrolling `recursive`, we get

```
for i2 = i+c to a
    recursive(i2, b-1)
```

which is

```
for i2 = i+c to a
   for i3 = i2+c to a
       recursive(i3, b-2)
```

which is

```
for i2 = i+c to a
   for i3 = i2+c to a
       for i4 = i3+c to a
           recursive(i4, b-3)
```

etc

As you can see, you have `b` nested loops that iterate over a subset of `a-c` elements. Applying what we learned above, `recursive` takes `O((a-c)b)` time.

The whole code (i.e. the call to `recursive` plus the outer loop) adds another layer, so it takes `O((a-c)b * a)` time.